# Ruby on Rails App assets not loading HTTP 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, http-status-code-404

estimatemyproject.com is running on ruby on rails for more than 2 years without any problems.
But just today it stopped loading assets . 
I searched online and tried

```
 rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

but it fails:

```
root@emp:/home/emp/current# rake assets:precompile --trace  RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/application.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(assets: %w(development test)))
                                   ^
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/application.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(assets: %w(development test)))
                                                         ^
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/application.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/Rakefile:5
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:27
```

Help me to debug this please! 
Need the assets to reload or refresh the cache somehow.

Thanks!

I tried using the change diego suggested :

It gives me a different error now.

rake aborted!

```
no such file to load -- rubygems
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/boot.rb:1:in `require'
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/boot.rb:1
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/config/application.rb:1
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/emp/emp/releases/20160127092918/Rakefile:5
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in     `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in    `standard_exception_handling'
```

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:27

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `config/application.rb` line 7.

Seems like you're using an old version of Ruby that does not support the colon hash syntax. Change this:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(assets: %w(development test)))
```

to:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

Fix that and redeploy your app and rerun the rake command.

Comment: I have changed this and rerun the app using "service thin restart" but now the server doesnt start. On the website it gives "502 Bad Gateway" . Cant seem to get the server up now.

Comment: make sure `bundle` works just in case you have a typo or other problem.